# prefers-color-scheme default styles vs light

Tags: css, media-queries, darkmode

Can i use:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
 color: pink;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
 color: pink;
}
```

instead of:

```
color: pink;

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
 color: pink;
}
```

I know it's good to leave support for older browsers. But is **light** the default theme value in modern browsers?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme for correct use of the media query and also this statement: light
Indicates that user has notified that they prefer an interface that has a light theme, or has not expressed an active preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, light color scheme is default on most devices and browsers. Also adding `@media` with light color scheme won't change anything since there are no other color schemes than light and dark.

Comment: Why won’t using a media query with light not change anything? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme seems to give an example.

Comment: @AHaworth You can copy that example and apply light color scheme. Nothing will change.